# NameError: name 'ni7MessageESt5dequeIS2_SaIS2_EEE5frontEvrames6resizeEjj' is not defined

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm using my raspberry pi zero w to make photos from my android device. It's been working for several months now and today when I was trying to make a picture I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 282, in make_raw
    take_pix(raw_file_name)
  File "main.py", line 262, in take_pi_pix
    import picamera
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
    from picamera.mmalobj import PiResolution, PiFramerateRange
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 50, in <module>
    from fractions import Fraction
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fractions.py", line 7, in <module>
    from decimal import Decimal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 140, in <module>
    import numbers as _numbers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/numbers.py", line 1, in <module>
    Vector_implC2Ev
NameError: name 'ni7MessageESt5dequeIS2_SaIS2_EEE5frontEvrames6resizeEjj' is not defined
```

the function that imports picamera:

```
def take_pix(file_name):
        import picamera
        print("About to take a picture")
        with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                # camera.resolution = (640,360)
                camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
                # camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)
                #camera.rotation = 180
                camera.capture(file_name)
        print("Picture taken")
```

I was searching for similar errors to this message but I found nothing similar. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the way you manipulate your photos?

Comment: I edited it, thx for your quick response

Comment: raspistill -vf -hf -o /home/pi/DATE.jpg
makes the picture!